# include_bytes! and arbitrary file length

Tags: rust

How can I change this function to accept inputs of various length?

```
fn main() {
    let bytes = include_bytes!("../arbitrary_length_input");
    let (x, y) = parse_input(&bytes);
}

fn parse_input(input: &&[u8]) -> (isize, isize) {
    let (x, y, _) = input
        .split(|b| b == &b'\n')
        .fold((0, 0, 0b01000100u8), |(x, y, d), i| {
            let v: isize = atoi::atoi(&i[1..]).unwrap();

            match i[0] {
                b'E' => x += y
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
        });
    (x, y)
}
```

Running this code returns this error:

```
expected slice `[u8]`, found array `[u8; 2761]`
```

Which makes sense because arrays have to be a certain length. How can I generalise the `parse_input()` function to accept a variety of files as inputs?

Comment: a slice of bytes (`&[u8]`) should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a signature of `&[u8]` and the method [`as_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.as_slice) for the byte array:

```rust
fn main() {
    let bytes = include_bytes!("../arbitrary_length_input");
    let (x, y) = parse_input(bytes.as_slice());
}

fn parse_input(input: &[u8]) -> (isize, isize) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `.as_slice()`, `bytes` is already a `&[u8; 2761]` which can be automatically coerced to `&[u8]`. OP only has the problem because the double-reference cannot be coerced.

Comment: You're both right, `.as_slice()` isn't required. Thanks so much.